# Amazon Appstore Deeplink to Manage Subscriptions

Tags: android, mobile, subscription, amazon-in-app-purchase

I'm trying to deeplink to the Amazon Appstore's Manage Subscriptions page from my app and I'm curious if it's possible. I've managed to accomplish this for the Google Play Store and iOS App Store.

I've gone through the documentation at the link below but there's no mention of linking to the Manage Subscriptions page.
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-deep-linking-to-the-amazon-client.html

The closest I've come to accomplishing what I want is opening this link:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/your-account/myapps/yoursubscriptions

This will open the right page on the devices browser, but I'd prefer if I could open to the Manage Subscriptions page in the Amazon Appstore app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is still not possible, see https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/16617/link-to-manage-subscription.html

> There is not a link that you as a developer would be able to use to allow a customer to be able to manage their subscriptions. You would need to have your customers go to manage their subscription either via one of the Amazon Apps on their device, or via the Amazon.com website under their user's profile.

Comment: Well, at least it's documented now!

Answer (score 1):

The scheme proposed by @levon actually works on Amazon Fire tablets, so the best solution would be to use it with a fallback, something like this:

```java
void openSubscriptionManagement() {
    try {
        // Open Amazon App Store to manage subscriptions
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("amzn://apps/library/subscriptions"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            String url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/your-account/myapps/yoursubscriptions";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error opening URL", e2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the scheme you want: "amzn://apps/library/subscriptions" and here's code that should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("amzn://apps/library/subscriptions"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Finally got around to testing this. It doesn't seem to work on Android devices that install the Amazon Appstore. I haven't had a chance to test on a Kindle device. Maybe it only works on those?

The error I get is:
`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=amzn://apps/library/subscriptions }`